# change the background color of the button

Tags: android

I want to change the background of this button:

```
              <Button
               android:id="@+id/button1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
               android:minHeight="106dp"
               android:text="Button" />
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make one buttoncolor.xml file and place this into:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF0000" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF0000" />
<item android:color="#ffffff" />
```

Then in your button attribute:

```
android:background="@drawable/buttoncolor"
```

Programmatically:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: You can also just do android:background="#FFFFFF" by color code

Comment: @user3731180 glad to help. if it works you can thick this as an answer.

Comment: are you sure,this answer will work?

Comment: modified it. this way should be more proper.

Answer (score 0):

Use android: background="" attribute to that button.
For example you can have #22CCDD in "" in the above line

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:background=""` the value can be color or drawable

Answer (score 0):

use the below as drawble file,let suppose button_bg.xml

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
 <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/> --> change any color here accorring  to your requirement,and this will the background of your button.
     <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"  --> use this if you want to make button corners rounded.
              android:bottomRightRadius="8dp" 
              android:topLeftRadius="8dp" 
              android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>

 <stroke android:width="1dp" --> use this if you want button border.
         android:color="#9c9a9b"/> --> change any color here accorring to your requirement
```

## Here is your button code

```
Button
           android:id="@+id/button1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
           android:minHeight="106dp"
           android:background="@drawable/button_bg" -- > set the above file like this.
           android:text="Button" />
```

Or simple  you can make a image and put that in your drawable folder and can set as button background like:

```
android:background="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"
```